# Is $E[W^2_{t}|F_s]$ a Martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

G'day, I am trying to find out mathematically if $W^2_{s}$ is a martingale.

Let $W^2_{s}$ be a Brownian motion, t>_0

$E[W^2_{t}|F_s] = E[(W_t-W_s +W_s)^2|F_s]$

$= E[(W_t-W_s)^2 - W^2_{s} +2(W_t-W_s)W_s|F_s]$

$*E[(W_t-W_s)^2] = Var[(W_t-Ws)] = t-s$

$= E[(t-s) - W^2_{s} +2(W_t-W_s)W_s|F_s]$

$* E[W^2_{s}] = s$

$= E[(t-s) - s +2(W_t-W_s)W_s|F_s]$

$* 2(W_t-W_s)W_s = 0?

$= E[(t-s) - s + 0|F_s]$

Can someone finish/correct what I started?

Comment: You have two time parameters; which one do you want it to be a martingale with respect to? Maybe you should cite the definition you want to satisfy.

Comment: Hey, Martingale wrt Brownian motion, can you check my math?

Comment: I think you are mixing notations like E[X|F], which are random variables and E[X] which are just deterministic functions...

Comment: Hi Thomas, you mean that $E[W_s]$ is deterministic hence a constant because it is known at time s?

Answer (score 2):

If $(W_t)$ is supposed to be Brownian Motion then $(E(W_t^{2}|\mathcal F_s))_{t \geq s}$ is not a martingale. If it is, then  $E(E(W_t^{2}|\mathcal F_s))$ would  not depend on $t$ but in this case, it is $t$.

[If $(X_t)$ is a martingale then  $EX_{t+s}=EX_t$ for all $t,s$ so $EX_t$ is independent of $t$].

Comment: Hey Kabo, thanks for your answer, It's indeed for t >= 0 and t>= s and W is indeed a Brownian motion. Is the math correct in this case?